# gcc compiler complain about test[0] error from char* test;

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, char

I simply write this:

```
char* test="test";
printf("%s",test[0]);
```

it says seg fault;
then I change to 
`printf("%s",&test[0]);` the error gone
But this is not what I want;
the console print: "test "
how to get just value "t" from that pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want just the `t`, you should do:

```
printf("%c",test[0]);
```

The format `%c`, will print a single `char`.

`%s` will print the entire null-terminated string.

Comment: remember that test[0] returns a char - and as Mystical said %s will treat it as a pointer to a string - a contrived example is that the first char is "A" this is 65 in ascii - when you use the %s it tried to find a string pointer located at memory address 0x41 - 99.99% likely to be out-of-scope of you own code

Comment: that makes more clean thanks,also I've noticed when I comparing with this single char test[0] equals something I need to write: =='t' instead of =="t",why?

Comment: That's because `'t'` is a char. Whereas `"t"` is a c-string. You can't compare a `char` to a c-string.

Answer (score 4):

You should use %c instead of %s as %s takes a char * and prints until \0. %c takes one single character instead.